# JK Flip Flop , Counter Sequence?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

Three edge-triggered JK flip-flops in a synchronous circuit have the following input conditions.

```
JA = QB     KA = 1
JB = 'QA    KB = 1
JC = QB     KC = 1
```

Assume that the initial state is `QA = 0    QB = 0     QC = 0` Find the count sequence

I'm having very difficulties how to solve this problem.

And also i found the answer. but no idea how they solved it? can anyone help me

Answer : http://bit.ly/1mhIosR

Comment: Why don't you begin by drawing a schematic of the circuit. You know what the J, K inputs are initially, so you can figure out what the Q outputs must be after a clock edge. Just repeat for as many clocks as necessary to see the pattern.

Comment: @JoeHass I know how to draw circuit when given counter sequence has given. but in this i don't know how to enter to the question. e.g. : why qa,qb,qc has 0,2,5 is it mandatory? etc.. and also JA not equal to QB in the answer

Comment: Use the information given about the connections of the J and K inputs to the Q outputs, and draw the schematic. If JA is not equal to QB then the answer you found is not the answer you need.

Comment: Note that by simple examination, the inputs to FF A and FF C are identical (and so are their initial states), so the QA and QC outputs will always be identical. This means that you really only need to consider QA and QB in your analysis. Also, there's no feedback from QC anyway.

Comment: I followed your link to the answer. JA is equal to QB.

Comment: @IamBatman - then you should post it as an answer (it's okay for you to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic table for JK Flip flop is

```
J    K   Input(Qn)     output(Qn+1) 

0    0       Qn            Qn
0    1       X             0
1    0       X             1
1    1       Qn            !Qn
```

As for initial combination mentioned QA = 0 QB = 0 QC = 0

```
For JA =  QB = 0    KA = 1 => QAnext = 0
    JB = 'QA = 1    KB = 1 => QBnext = 1
    JC =  QB = 0    KC = 1 => QCnext = 0
```

Hence we got 2. Now taking this combination of QA = 0 QB = 1 QC = 0; we can find the next output. In this way the process is repeated until an already produced output is obtained again so that a sequence is formed

Comment: Did you notice in the comments that the OP solved the problem 20 hours ago?

Comment: I have seen after putting my answer, as OP didn't wrote his version I think it may help people looking at it. So I didn't removed it.